# Determining which algorithm is asymptotically faster

Tags: algorithm

how would you be able to determine if one algorithm is asymptotically faster than another? Say one equation is t(n) = 7t(n/2) + n^2 and the other is t(n)= aT(n/4) + n^2. how would you determine for  which value of a would that equation be faster than the first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly an expert on analyzing algorithm performance, but...

Asymptotically, you take the greatest of the two terms to determine the growth of the algorithm. So you would have to determine the value of "a" that causes the first term to have a higher growth rate than the second term, but since we are also comparing this to the first equation, it has to have a higher growth rate than it as well. According to the master theorem, that would be where n<sup>log<sub>b</sub> a</sup> > f(n).

Using the values in your example f(n) = n<sup>2</sup>, b = 4. So you would have to solve    Log<sub>4</sub> a > Log<sub>2</sub> 7 > 2 for a. Which is approx. 48.5

Edit:
This isn't what i used as a source, but i decided to do some googling to find a supportive source.
https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf

Comment: Thanks! One more questions. what does Asymptotically really mean? I searched it up on google but couldn't get the grasp of it.

Comment: Basically, it means we care about the performance with large amounts of input. An Asymptote is a part of a line that approaches, but never reaches zero on one axis as it approaches infinity on the other.